# File names matching "..\ThirdParty\dlls\*.dll"

Tags: c#, filenames, glob

Is there an easy way to get a list of filenames that matach a filename pattern *including references to parent directory*? What I want is for `"..\ThirdParty\dlls\*.dll"` to return a collection like `["..\ThirdParty\dlls\one.dll", "..\ThirdParty\dlls\two.dll", ...]`

I can find several questions relating matching files names including full path, wildcards, but nothing that includes "..\" in the pattern. `Directory.GetFiles` explicitly disallows it.

What I want to do with the names is to include them in a **zip archive**, so if there is a zip library that can understand relative paths like this I am happier to use that.

The pattern(s) are coming from an input file, they are not known at compile time. They can get quite complex, e.g `..\src\..\ThirdParty\win32\*.dll` so parsing is probably not feasible.

Having to put it in zip is also the reason I am not very keen on converting the pattern to fullpath, I *do* want the relative paths in zip.

EDIT: **What I am looking for really is a C# equivalent of /bin/ls.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static string[] FindFiles(string path)
{
    string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path); // seperate directory i.e. ..\ThirdParty\dlls
    string filePattern = Path.GetFileName(path); // seperate file pattern i.e. *.dll

    // if path only contains pattern then use current directory
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(directory))
        directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

    //uncomment the following line if you need absolute paths
    //directory = Path.GetFullPath(directory); 

    if (!Directory.Exists(directory))      
        return new string[0];

    var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, filePattern); 
    return files;
}
```

Comment: `Path` is what I needed :) The only problem was that this returned *absolute* names while I needed *relative*. Removing `Path.GetFullPath` call took care of that. Would it be ok to change your answer accordingly so that it exactly matches what I asked for?

Comment: @HemalPandya I think for others a more general approach might be more relevant. So lets leave it as it is.

Comment: But without the change it is not the correct answer to my question, since I specifically asked for relative paths :( Perhaps you can change it so that it returns relative paths and also put a note on how to get full paths which may be more relevant in other cases?

Answer (score 3):

There is the Path.GetFullPath() function that will convert from relative to absolute. You could use it on the path part.

```
string pattern = @"..\src\..\ThirdParty\win32\*.dll";

string relativeDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(pattern);
string absoluteDir = Path.GetFullPath(relativeDir);
string filePattern = Path.GetFileName(pattern);

foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(absoluteDir, filePattern))
{

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I prepared my answer in the same time as you apparently… Anyway, yours is more complete.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you could use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` in combination with a regular expression like this (I haven't tested it though):

```
var matcher = new Regex(@"^\.\.\\ThirdParty\\dlls\\[^\\]+.dll$");
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("..", "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
{
    if (matcher.IsMatch(file))
        yield return file;
}
```

Comment: I am using .NET 3.5 while this function seems to be only in 4+. Besides, the pattern to match is not available at compile time and may contain arbitrary paths (`"..\..\bin\..\lib\x.dll"`...its ugly but happens), this approach will require me to parse the the pattern which is not feasible. Also I don't know if the name returned the function will be relative. But your answer shows some ambiguity in my question so it will help me clarify.